# How to bind list of arrays to datagrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have list of arrays containing double type data. I tried to bind this list directly to *datagrid.itemsource*, but datagrid didn't display any data, instead it displayed the properties of list items, such as item length, data type etc.

If not converting this list of arrays to 2D array, is it still possible to display this list in datagrid.

Besides, i'd also like to update this datagrid eveytime a new list entry comes in. how should I realize it.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to investigate using a data template - to configure exactly how to display your data, if you haven't done so already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Answer (score 0):

You should put some parts of your code in your question so we see what you are currently doing, I assume you are doing MVVM and you have implemented your ViewModel.

You should use  `ObservableCollection<double[]>` instead of `List<double[]>`, if a new item get inserted or deleted from ObservableCollection UI updates automatically. In your view model put an `ObservableCollection<double[]>` like:

```
public ObservableCollection<double[]> Collection
{
    set
    {
        collection= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
    }
    get { return collection; }
}
```

and then your UI should be something like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Collection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                           <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                         <TextBlock Text={Binding} Margin="5,0"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                           </ListBox>
                     </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If not converting this list of arrays to 2D array, is it still possible to display this list in datagrid.

Yes, but you need to create the columns yourself explicitly. Consider this example:

```
double[] row1 = new double[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
double[] row2 = new double[4] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
double[] row3 = new double[4] { 1, 3, 2, 1 };
List<double[]> sourceCollection = new List<double[]> { row1, row2, row3 };
dataGrid.ItemsSource = sourceCollection;
for (int i = 0; i<sourceCollection[0].Length; ++i)
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Binding = new Binding("[" + i.ToString() + "]") });
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" />
```

> Besides, i'd also like to update this datagrid eveytime a new list entry comes in. how should I realize it.

Replace the `List<double[]>` with an `ObservableCollection<double[]>`. You will then be able to add new rows (`double` arrays) to the `ObservableCollection<double[]>` dynamically and see these show up in the `DataGrid`.